# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource on ASP.Net Core migration from VS2015 to VS2017

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, facebook-login, visual-studio-2017

I have a web in ASP.Net Core (4.6.1 framework) that uses Facebook and MS external login that I created with Visual Studio 2015 and opened in the new Visual Studio 2017 that came out yesterday. VS2017 made a few changes related to the csproj, project.json, etc files.

The site compiled and executed fine except for one part. If I did a Facebook or Microsoft external login, the site displayed this trap:

```
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
AggregateException: Unhandled remote failure.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler+<HandleRemoteCallbackAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
```

The url in the browser showed that it was attempting to return from the external login to the local (https://localhost:44321/signin-facebook?code=... or /signin-microsoft).

The version number of the System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll (and System.Net.Http.dll) is 4.6.24705.1.

I started a new VS2017 project from scratch with Facebook and MS login added and it worked fine - getting me logged on without the trap. The dll's were the same versions.

Comparing the two csproj files showed differences but nothing obvious (nothing related to System dlls):

[image: Differences in csproj file]

Comment: Could you share what the differences in the project files are? It's possible that something references that assembly transitively.

Comment: Screenshot of csproj diffs added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41550563/system-net-http-nuget-package-4-3-0-reference-generates-system-io-fileloadexcept/50254508#50254508

Answer (score 43):

What solved it for me was to add a NuGet reference to System.Net.Http (version 4.3.1) to the newly migrated project.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/

Comment: Thank you, i hit the same error today upgrading my project to VS2017

Comment: This error hit us too. Here’s a related bug on GitHub for reference: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/487

Comment: Looks like their solution was to add System.Net.Http as well.

Comment: @Haukman After bringing my XUnit projects over from VS2015 to VS2017 I let it do its thing and replace the project.json files with .csproj and kept getting this System.Diagnostics error. My test project references a dll that makes API calls that uses System.Net.Http. Why in the world would the test project need to reference this to work? Somehow if I run the tests using the ReSharper Xunit test tool this reference is not needed.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but it may be that one of the dependencies are using it and doesn't have it listed as a NuGet dependency. I think the System.Net.Http is a little "special" since it's also included natives in the .NET Framework, it always seems to be the dependency that messes up my project, adding it "solves" a lot of issues.

Comment: I was using OpenTelemetry with Http library but it must not have included the required dependency in install when I installed the package. Thanks!

Comment: An update to 4.3.1 from 4.3.0 worked for me too. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

In References 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource' not included in solution

On installing latest version "5.0.1" of 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource' in NUget solved my issue. Hope it will fix yours also.

Answer (score 12):

The recommended answer did not resolve my issue.  I was getting this error when trying to reference a .Net 4.6.2 lib in a .Net Core 2 project.

To resolve the issue I had to add the Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility nuget package.
Credit to: https://medium.com/@ans_ashkan/asp-net-core-and-windows-event-log-75770a80a666

Comment: Lifesaver! I got bummed by nuget for updating a package this sorted me out!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and weirdly enough, problem resolved with updating **Microsoft.ApplicationInsights** versions. 2.20.0 is the version to go (for me). I don't know the connection between these packages but that's what happened.

Comment: Upgraded Microsoft.ApplicationInsights to 2.21.0 and it worked for me

Comment: It seems like older versions have this issue, and you need to upgrade the version, according to the requirements by any of the dependencies installed on your application.

Answer (score 3):

People using .NET Core web applications monitored with Application Insights hosted in App Services facing this issue

This when .NET Core web application has a dependency on 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource%u2019 binary and has this binary file deployed to /wwwroot/ folder, which is rare.

Work Around:  Please set previous version of monitoring extension by changing this app setting if you experience the above issue: ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSIONVERSION=2.8.24

After doing this please restart the application.

Here is the [source](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Monitor-Status/Issues-with-Net-Core-web-applications-in-App-Services-monitored/ba-p/1003392)

Answer (score 1):

In my case there were some binding redirect setting in web.config file but these files were missing in bin directory after removing these setting from web.config file resolved this issue
[image]

credit to [our-azure-app-service-fails-to-start-with-er](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1035793/our-azure-app-service-fails-to-start-with-below-er)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue when trying to open a connection to a database in an azure function. Adding the correct nuget package (System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource Version 7.0.0) didn't help. But a clean and rebuild in VS solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `web.config` does not have multiple `bindingRedirect` properties for `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource`.

Somehow I had two; one was correctly updated by Nuget when installing the latest package, but the other still had some old values in it which caused the bindingRedirect to try to load an older version of the dll.  I deleted the older bindingRedirect and that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Binding redirects may be missing, or incorrect.

Different dependencies (e.g. NuGet packages) may be trying to load different versions of a library, causing the failure. Binding redirects then fix this by selecting a single version to load, usually the newest. If they are not set up properly, the mentioned error may occur.

Full credit to Nick Craver and his excellent blog post:
https://nickcraver.com/blog/2020/02/11/binding-redirects/

I'll include a portion of the blog post here:

> 1. Enable `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>` (this doesn’t work for web projects - it doesn’t handle web.config)
>
> Note: this isn’t always perfect. It doesn’t handle all transitive
> cases especially around multi-targeting and conditional references.
>
> 2. Build with Visual Studio and hope it has warnings and a click to fix (this usually works)
>
> Note: this isn’t always perfect either, hence the “hope”.
>
> 3. Manually edit your *.config file.
>
> This is the surest way (and what Visual Studio is doing above), but
> also the most manual and/or fun on upgrades.

In my case, option 2 worked great - it was quick an painless. Thanks, Mark!

Solutions suggested in other answers may very well work, as, for example, adding direct a NuGet package reference will often set up a binding redirect, but adding a direct reference is unnecessary since your project doesn't really use it.