Error creating new instance of ef core context in new Inventor 2025 addin
I am creating an addin for Inventor 2025 using its own vb.net addin template.
It needs to interact with a sql server database (load drawing info and saving parts lists).
When I create the new instance of the dbcontext I get the following error.
I used entity developer to create an efml file and these work in other projects.
Not seen this error before?


Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/42704058/832052
